# TFS 2012 Scrum - Sprint cycle showing incorrectly in the backlog page

Tags: tfs, iteration, scrum, sprint

We started using TFS 2012 recently for SCRUM methodology and below is our current structure. We have issue with showing the sprint cycles in the Product Backlog page:

```
>     Team Project 1
>       |_Iteration 1
>          |_   Sprint 1 of Iteration 1 (Start Date: 04/7/2014 End Date: 04/25/2014) 
>       |_Iteration 2
>          |_   Sprint 1 of Iteration 2 (Start Date: 04/7/2014 End Date: 04/11/2014) 
>          |_   Sprint 2 of Iteration 2 (Start Date: 04/14/2014 End Date: 04/18/2014) 
>          |_   Sprint 3 of Iteration 2 (Start Date: 04/21/2014 End Date: 04/25/2014) 
>          |_   Sprint 4 of Iteration 2 (Start Date: 04/28/2014 End Date: 05/2/2014) 
>           
>           
>     When I look at the Product Backlog Page, this is what I see:
>     Current
>       |_  Sprint 1 of Iteration 1 (Start Date: 04/7/2014 End Date: 04/25/2014)    
>     Future
>       |_  Sprint 1 of Iteration 2 (Start Date: 04/7/2014 End Date: 04/11/2014) 
>       |_  Sprint 2 of Iteration 2 (Start Date: 04/14/2014 End Date: 04/18/2014) 
>       |_  Sprint 3 of Iteration 2 (Start Date: 04/21/2014 End Date: 04/25/2014) 
>       |_  Sprint 4 of Iteration 2 (Start Date: 04/28/2014 End Date: 05/2/2014)
```

The configuration shown in the backlog page is incorrect, because the "Sprint 1 of 
Iteration 2" is the past completed sprint which is showing in the future, while "Sprint 2
of Iteration 2" is the current sprint which is showing under the future. Is there any 
configuration change that needs to be made in TFS 2012?

Answer (score 0):

Your iteration dates are problematic. Iterations aren't parallel processed timeboxes. You should think them as upper sprints.

So in your example sprint 1 of iteration 1 and 2 seem to be starting on the same date whereas such a thing can't be happening. You can't jump to iteration 2 before completing iteration 1. I think you are using the iterations as project branches, am I right?

Comment: Enmos, thanks for the response. You are correct. We are using iterations as projects. We have two teams working on a single project parallely one in offshore and one onsite. We want to track the progress on each team separately. Two iterations with multiple sprints on each iteration runs at the same time. Is there a way to do this in TFS 2012?

Comment: There is a single team model which could help you. I, personally couldn't get used to it. http://blog.nwcadence.com/working-within-a-single-team-project-with-team-foundation-server-2012/